# How to search many fields and against many values in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, search

I'm writing a web application with a search function. I'm searching for a list of "Assets".

An Asset has a Name and a Description. It also has a list of tags associated with it.

My schema looks like this:

[image: Schema]
My input looks like this: "many key words"

My question is what's the best way to search for the assets. Also keeping in mind that there will more than likely be many more fields that need to be searched in the future.

My ideas are the following:

**Idea 1:**

Procedurally create a massive query like:

```
      select * 
      from asset 
      where id in (
         select asset_id 
         from asset_tag 
         where tag_id in (
            select id
            from tags
            where name in (
               'many', 'key', 'words'
            )
         )
     ) or (concat(name, description) like '%many%' 
       or concat(name, description) like '%key%' 
       or concat(name, description) like '%words%')
```

This isn't particularly good as the fields I might need to add more fields to search and I have a feeling when the database starts to get some size this isn't going to work at all.

**Idea 2:**

Create some sort of indexing system. where I create another table called 'asset_index' with two columns in it. Asset_id and text. when an asset gets updated, or tag added I calculate the text field on the asset_index so its a concatenation of all of the things I want to search. so my table will look like:

[image: asset index]

So my query would be something like:

```
select * 
from asset 
where id in (
    select asset_id 
    from asset_index 
    where match(text) against('many key words') 
    -- or text like '%many%' or  text like '%key%' or  text like '%words%' depending up if I can get the database to support full text searches
)
```

Or is there a better way? 3rd party indexing service?

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server? Can't be both...

Comment: use REGEX to match the string into mysql

Comment: what is the size of tables? It doesn't matter if query is massive it should perform well.

Comment: you can use FULLTEXT index to search in many field for value. It also give you relevant search.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, just search for the asset. Maybe I'm missing something, in which case a replicable example might help

Comment: Its MySql but I was wondering what the best way (generic way??) of handling searching many columns and related tables for info is. My question is really whats the best way to aggregate many tables and columns to return a single row. If that make sense.

Comment: The asset table is about 50000 rows, the asset_tag table is about 600000 rows and the tag table is close to 500 tags.

Answer (score 0):

try this for mysql which returns matched values

```
where text RLIKE '(many)|(key)|(words)'
```

or

```
where text RLIKE '[many]|[key]|[words]'
```